# Any workarounds for ocsp stapling in erlang OTP 25?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

Seems ocsp stapling is still a wip in otp 25.

Is there any workarounds to manually fetch the ocsp status, and specify the certificate status tls extension ?

If i pass : {ocsp_stapling, true}, in my SSLOpts, i get :

TLS client: In state certify at ssl_handshake.erl:363 generated CLIENT ALERT: Fatal - Internal Error

- {unexpected_error,badarg}
  ** exception error: no match of right hand side value {error,{tls_alert,{internal_error,"TLS client: In state certify at ssl_handshake.erl:363 generated CLIENT ALERT: Fatal - Internal Error\n {unexpected_error,badarg}"}}}